# Can an CognitoUserPool be used with a client without a clientSecret?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In the AWS Cognito developer guide the CognitoUserPool object is always created with a client secret.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-android.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-console-android

The AWS console let me create clients without a secret key.

Is it possible to use a client with "(no secret key)" in Android?
If so, how?

Thank you

Comment: how did you get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just remember in the `application` settings within your Cognito pool (where you get the `appId`), to not tick having the `secret key` option .